Using point styling with dense line charts
My chart has lines which are quite close together, but still need to be differentiated in the legend. There are a few hundred datapoints for this line charts, so when I use pointstyle to differentiate them I get the following result:

The points are only readable in the very vertical parts of the graph. How can I make the markers evenly spaced?
I've used scriptable options with radius to only turn on ever nth point, but then I am left with underdense areas when the points have large vertical gaps:

I've tried to use dash-style to differentiate them, but that has been quite unreadable:

My attempt at enabling points based on the distance to the previously enabled point failed because I wasn't able to figure out how to access the radii of other points in the graph:
new Chart({
  options: {
    elements: {
      point: {
        radius: spacePoints
      }
    }
  }
})

function spacePoints(context) {
  var POINT_SPACING = 10
  var data = context.dataset.data
  var x = context.parsed.x
  var y = context.parsed.y
  // iterate backwards through previous points
  for (let i = context.dataIndex - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var point = data[i]
    // when you find the previous point in the graph that has been "enabled"
    if (point.radius != 0) { // <--- PROBLEM: `point` only has x and y values, not point options
      //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      var absoluteXDist = (x - point.x) / 15 * 900 //factor at the end to compensate for scale bounds and width on screen
      var absoluteYDist = (y - point.y) / 100 * 380
      var distance = Math.sqrt(absoluteXDist ** 2 + absoluteYDist ** 2)
      if (distance > POINT_SPACING) {
        return 8
      } else {
        return 0
      }
    }
  }
}


You may try data decimation, but I doubt it is suitable to this problem.

Otherwise, the logic of your spacePoints function could be improved, by saving the last point with radius > 0 and comparing the current point with that, or even saving a sorted array of points if that won't take too long. However, no serious contributor here will ever write such a specific answer without testing their code. That's why you should provide a minimal reproducible example, that is a runnable version of your code, including data. If that is too big, you can put it in a jsFiddle, codepen, stackblitz, codesandbox, etc...

I have found a quick and dirty solution that worked for me. My main goal was readability, and the aesthetic results are arguably bad. I hope this is helpful if someone runs into a similar issue.
I used scriptable options for the radius:
new Chart(ctx, {
   options: {
     elements: {
       point: {
         radius: spacePoints
       }
      }
    },
    data: data
});

And my spacePoints code was based on the fact that all my data is evenly spaced, so points on the line with lower slope will be more dense:
function spacePoints(context, RADIUS) {
  var index = context.dataIndex;
  var x = context.parsed.x;
  var y = context.parsed.y;
  if (index == 0) {
    return RADIUS;
  }

  var lastEnabledPoint = context.dataset.data[index - 1];

  var lastPointX = lastEnabledPoint.x;
  var lastPointY = lastEnabledPoint.y;
  var slope = Math.abs(y - lastPointY);
  
   // only show 1 every 8 points for a low slope
   // show 1 every 2 points for a medium slope
   //show every point for a high slope
   // you will need to tweak these factors for your code.
  if (slope < 2) {
    return index % 8 ? 0 : RADIUS;
  } else if (slope < 5) {
    return index % 2 ? 0 : RADIUS;
  } else {
    return RADIUS;
  }
}

Here is what the resulting graph looks like:
quick and dirty solution
Note the uneven spacing, this is the main flaw with this quick-and-dirty solution.
